# Worst-Case Runtime Recurrence: Data Structure and Big-O Analysis

Tags: java, data-structures, runtime, big-o

so I have a homework for data structure and big-O analysis, and big-O is still a very new concept to me so I'm still trying to grasp it. In one of the problems, I was told to find the recurrence of the worst-case runtime for the following code:

```
g(n){
  if(n == 1){
     return 1000;
  }
  if(g(n/4) > 6){
     return 6 * g(n/4);
  }
  else{
     return 4 * g(n/4);
  }
}
```

I am at a loss at how to approach this problem! I think the best case might be O(1), that is if n is immediately 1 then it will return 1000 and the code finishes. But I have no idea how to solve for the worst-case runtime! Do I need to focus on the second if statement and the else, assuming that it will take a significantly long time for g(n/4) > 6?

If anyone have any insights on this, I would really appreciate it... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Big O notation only cares asymptotic growth of the running time.

So the best case is not `O(1)`, since this holds only for a fixed `n`.

If you look at the code, you notice that for every case with `n > 1`, `g(n/4)` is called. So if `n` is greater than `1`, it is divided by `4` (called two times, one time to evaluate `g(n/4) > 6` and one time for returning `g(n/4)`) . The time recurrence equation is

```
T(n) = 2⋅T(n/4) + Θ(1)
```

You can expand this to

```
T(n) = T(n/4c) + Σk=1,...,c 2c⋅Θ(1)
```

This terminates with `n / 4c = 1` or `n = 4c`. This holds for `c = log₄(n)` and you get

```
T(n) = Θ(1) ⋅ (2 + 4 + ... + 2log₄(n)) = 20.5⋅log₂(n) + 1 - 2 = 2⋅(sqrt(n) - 1) = Θ(sqrt(n))
```

Alternatively, you can use the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Notice: The code you posted has the same best case complexity and worst case complexity.

Comment: thank you! I also found the big-O notation, which is O(log(n)), because the  equation has the general form Clog4(n) + 2T(n/4). What I'm confused with now is finding its closed form... Computing the algorithm for every n and finding a common pattern seems rather confusing for me; I'm not sure how exactly to solve this part of the problem.